# Displaying images from an array doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

So i've got this line of code

```js
var imagesArray = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png","19.png","20.png","21.png" ];

var newArray = new Array(100);

var repeatImage = null;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  if (i === 9)
  {
    repeatImage = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
    newArray[i] = repeatImage;
  }

  else if(i % 9 === 0)
  {
    newArray[i] = repeatImage;
  }
  else
  {
    newArray[i] = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
  }
}
```

And i need those images to show in my document.write

```js
document.write("<img src='images/smileys" + imagesArray [i] + "'/>" + newArray[i] ");
```

but it doesn't seem to work , i guess my document.write is wrong but i dont really know where

Comment: do you get any error in your code? what is the output of the document.write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra double quote `"` in the end of `document.write` you should remove it :

```
document.write("<img src='images/smileys" + imagesArray [i] + "'/>" + newArray[i] ");
__________________________________________________________________________________^
```

Should be :

```
document.write("<img src='images/smileys" + imagesArray [i] + "'/>" + newArray[i]);
```

And you should add the `document.write` in the end of the `for` loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ...

    document.write("<img src='images/smileys" + imagesArray [i] + "'/>" + newArray[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now it shows undefined

Comment: @RalfsR check my update (you should add `document.write` inside for loop).

Comment: it now shows a bunch of undefined http://puu.sh/npBKZ/af6f642063.png

Comment: Not for me it show the img names, try to use the code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/44/.

Comment: This breaks my code of every 9th element in Array being the same

Comment: http://puu.sh/npCEi/03c5af14f6.png oh we forgot to put images/smileys/ a slash after smileys/ so now it shows me like this, which is broken

Comment: Good job, now i guess you have something wrong in the flow of your loop.

Comment: Yeah i guess! At the first blink of an eye, could you tell me what possibly is wrong with it? I basically need every 9th element of an array 9th, 18th, 27th ... etc. till 99 to be the same image but so that by refreshing the page each time it would be different image

Comment: Yes, i see that your `for` loop will loop 100 time but you have just 21 picture so when `i` become `22` it'll try to show `imagesArray [22]` or `imagesArray [23]`... it will not found any image.

Comment: How do i make it so it loops images more than once?

Comment: I think using the same `newArray[i]` in the both positions will solve the issue, try `document.write("<img src='images/smileys" + newArray[i] + "'/>" + newArray[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.write('<img src="images/smileys '+imagesArray [i]+'" /> + '+newArray[i]);
```

working here

```js
var imagesArray = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png", "10.png", "11.png", "12.png", "13.png", "14.png", "15.png", "16.png", "17.png", "18.png", "19.png", "20.png", "21.png"];

var newArray = new Array(100);

var repeatImage = null;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if (i === 9) {
    repeatImage = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
    newArray[i] = repeatImage;
  } else if (i % 9 === 0) {
    newArray[i] = repeatImage;
  } else {
    newArray[i] = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
  }
  document.write('<img src="images/smileys '+imagesArray [i]+'" /> + '+newArray[i]);
}
```